# How should I query key-value pairs in this scenario?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I'm trying to query 2 separate key-value pairs as follows:
AttributeTable contains 3 columns [of interest]

```
ID       KeyColumn     ValueColumn
12345    Sector        Sector 1
12345    Group         Group X
```

I need to query to get the following output:

```
ID      Sector     Group
12345   Sector 1   Group X
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT ID, (SELECT VALUECOLUMN WHERE KEYCOLUMN = 'Sector') as Sector,(SELECT VALUECOLUMN WHERE KEYCOLUMN = 'Group') as Group
FROM AttributeTable 
GROUP BY ID, KEYCOLUMN, VALUECOLUMN
```

Obviously, this is wrong since it gives me duplicates [1 row each for the 3 columns per ID]

How would I do this to get the desired output?

Comment: That sure looks like a PIVOT to me... you want the rows returned as columns... is that correct?

Comment: Correct. One solution I thought of was to Union the two data sets, one with each filter ["sector" and "group"] but I need to use this data to perform a  number of other operations and it could get messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (ID INT, KeyColumn VARCHAR(10), ValueColumn VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
(12345    ,'Sector'    ,    'Sector 1'),
(12345    ,'Group'     ,    'Group X')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM @TABLE
        PIVOT (MAX(ValueColumn)
               FOR KeyColumn
               IN ([Sector] , [Group]))p
```

**Result**

```
╔═══════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║  ID   ║  Sector  ║  Group  ║
╠═══════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║ 12345 ║ Sector 1 ║ Group X ║
╚═══════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: I'm giving this a shot. Thank you

Comment: Can you explain why this would work? I tried it with my data set and I still get duplicates. `[12345 NULL NULL], [12345 Sector 1 NULL],[12345 NULL Group X]`

Comment: I did get this to work. Small note: I did have a few other `Keys` in addition to the two [sector,group] which was what was causing duplicates. Filtering them out from the dataset did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you need an alternative to `PIVOT`, the views I've seen used for Entity-Attribute-Value tables look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.ID
    f1.ValueColumn AS "Sector",
    f2.ValueColumn AS "Group"
FROM AttributeTable a
LEFT JOIN AttributeTable f1 ON f1.ID = a.ID AND f1.KeyColumn = 'Sector'
LEFT JOIN AttributeTable f2 ON f2.ID = a.ID AND f2.KeyColumn = 'Group'
```

And so on with one join for each field.  Dynamically generating them is a huge pain in the ass, and `PIVOT` is only slightly better since that isn't dynamic either.  If you have a reason to avoid aggregates (if `ValueColumn` is a `BIT`, for example) this might help.

Comment: You were right. This does work, but in my case, the performance difference was quite large. It might have had something to do with the fact that I'm accessing a linked server but `join` vs `pivot` was about 3X longer.

Comment: @GVashist No, the query plan for `PIVOT` is always a lot cleaner than this is.  This is what people used when `PIVOT` didn't exist.  It's ugly and it's gross, but sometimes it's all that you can do!

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help. And without pivots

```
SELECT a.ID,Max(decode(a.keycolumn,'Group',a.ValueColumn,null))AS "group",
Max(decode(a.keycolumn,'Sector',a.ValueColumn,null))AS "Sector" 
FROM AttributeTable where KeyColumn in ( 'Group','Sector')
Group by a.id;
```